# Change font size and restrict text length in Plotly hover text (Python)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a plotly scatter plot consisting of 9 trace scatter plots on one that is going into a Dash Dashboard.

I have only provided the first trace to make the code shorter and easier but If you need to see the other 8 I can provide them (they are all similar to this trace).

I need help to do the following:

1. Change the font-size of the hover text
2. Give a cut-off length to the hover text as at the moment it continues off the page.

   ```
   trace0= go.Scatter(
       x =df[df['Topic'] == 'Time consuming tasks']['x'],
       y = df[df['Topic'] == 'Time consuming tasks']['y'],
       mode = 'markers',
       text= df[df['Topic'] == 'Time consuming tasks']['challenges'],
       marker = dict(      
           size = 9,
           line = dict(
               width = 2,
           )
       ),
   name = 'First Plot',
   showlegend=True)



   app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='scatterplot',
                                           figure = {'data' : [trace0, trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4, trace5, trace6, trace7, trace8],
                                           'layout' : go.Layout(title='Biggest hindrances in your life?',
                                                                 xaxis = {'title':'x axis'},
                                                                 yaxis = {'title': 'y axis'},
                                                                height = 550,
                                                                titlefont= {'size':33},
                                                                hovermode = 'closest',                                                                                                                                  
                                                                legend=dict(

                                                                             traceorder='normal',
                                                                             font=dict(
                                                                                       family='sans-serif',
                                                                                       size=25,
                                                                                       color='#000'
                                                                                      )
                                                                            )
                                                                )           
                                                   }                       


                                   )
                         ])
   ```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

I did not run your full example, however, in my case, the following solved the issue:

```
go.Layout(title='Biggest hindrances in your life?',
          #other options for the plot
           hoverlabel=dict(font=dict(family='sans-serif', size=25)))
```

Hope that answeres point 1.

*Edit*

Just found this page, might also be useful
https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/

Comment: Nice questions about changing the color in plotly go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63723456/how-to-plot-discrete-colours-with-plotly?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604342/plotly-how-to-set-up-a-color-palette-for-a-figure-created-with-multiple-traces?noredirect=1&lq=1