# How to plot discrete colours with plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

My code so far:

```
fig2 = plotly.subplots.make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)
fig2.append_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=df['Date_Time'], y=df["N2O_rSig"]), row=1, col=1)
                   
fig2.append_trace(                   
        go.Scatter(x=df['Date_Time'], y=df["Flow_rSig"]), row=2, col=1)
        
fig2.append_trace(   
        go.Scatter(x=df['Date_Time'], y=df["O2_rSig"]), row=3, col=1)
   
fig2.update_layout(title_text="Stacked Subplots")

fig2.write_html("test_plotly.html")
```

For each trace I want to have a discrete color governed by Valve_ai but I just can't seem to find the right way. Is there a way without having to rebuild that way my data is sent to Plotly.graph_objects.

I noticed Plotly Express has the ability to split long data based on the variable "color". Cufflinks also manages this with categories. However I in order to manage Legends across multiple subplots Plotly.go seems like the only option.

Here is the example data

```
,Unnamed: 0,Date_Time,N,Valve_ai,N2O_rSig,NO_rSig,O2_rSig,CO2_rSig,Flow_rSig
48,57,2020-07-15 00:00:57,58,Bio1 G1,6.33,16.69,20.61,1.0,1.02
49,58,2020-07-15 00:00:58,59,Bio1 G1,6.13,16.62,20.61,1.0,0.96
50,59,2020-07-15 00:00:59,60,Bio1 G1,6.15,16.56,20.6,1.0,0.98
51,60,2020-07-15 00:01:00,61,Bio1 G1,6.12,16.55,20.59,1.0,0.86
52,61,2020-07-15 00:01:01,62,Bio1 G1,6.44,16.68,20.6,1.0,1.07
53,62,2020-07-15 00:01:02,63,Bio1 G1,6.69,16.63,20.59,1.0,0.94
54,64,2020-07-15 00:01:04,65,Bio1 G2,7.28,16.69,20.57,1.0,0.98
55,65,2020-07-15 00:01:05,66,Bio1 G2,7.98,17.06,20.49,1.0,1.05
56,66,2020-07-15 00:01:06,67,Bio1 G2,8.82,17.37,20.4,1.0,0.98
57,67,2020-07-15 00:01:07,68,Bio1 G2,10.03,17.78,20.26,1.0,0.9
58,68,2020-07-15 00:01:08,69,Bio1 G2,13.4,19.36,19.94,1.0,1.02
59,69,2020-07-15 00:01:09,70,Bio1 G2,15.55,20.68,19.77,1.0,0.85
```

Comment: Does the post [Plotly: How to define colors in a figure using plotly.graph_objects and plotly.express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460213/plotly-how-to-define-colors-in-a-figure-using-plotly-graph-objects-and-plotly-e/63460218#63460218) not answer your question?

Comment: So I am looking for the exact reverse of that question. I have already made a plot with plotly.express that perfectly separates lines/colours based on the value in `df['Valve_ai]` Now I'm looking to do the same with Plotly.graph_objects instead of using plotly express (px). This is because I need to create a couple of subplots which according to the documentation isn't possible with px.

Comment: If you include your data sample in your code snippet and make sure it produces a fig, I'll take a closer look at it within an hour.

Comment: Cheers vestland, I found the solution now and have put it as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of looking around I found a direct comparison with bar graphs
[on the plotly website](https://plotly.com/python/graph-objects/)

The following code allowed me to split up my Data Frame based on Valve and then iterate through each DF to create individual traces.

```
for valve, group in df.groupby("Valve_ai"):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=group["Date_Time"], y=group["N2O_rSig"], name=valve)
```

Comment: Nicely done! Why don't you include some figures there to spice it up a bit?